# EOSError 1410 при работе с TFileStream.Create

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

**UPD**: Опытным путём выяснил, что вылет вообще не зависит от содержимого блока `except`.

Идея была такая, что программа читает файл конфига в директории с экзешником, а если его нет - создаёт. На деле, если файл есть, программа читает конфиг, а если нет - идёт к `except` и... вылетает с исключением `EOSError 1410: Class Already Exists` на первой же строчке. Добавил в начало `except` `FStream.Free` - теперь вылетает на нём. Его надо как-то по-другому освобождать, или дело вообще не в TFileStream?

```
try
      FStream:=TFileStream.Create('config.json',fmOpenRead);
      try
        try
          JParser:=TJSONParser.Create(FStream);
          try
            JData:=JParser.Parse;
            JObject := TJSONObject(JData);
            GamePath := JObject.Get('GamePath');
            UserPath := JObject.Get('UserPath');
            NumActiveMods := JData.FindPath('ActiveMods').Count;
            SetLength(ActiveMods, NumActiveMods);
            for i := 0 to NumActiveMods-1 do
              ActiveMods[i] := JData.FindPath('ActiveMods['+IntToStr(i)+']').AsString;
            n := JData.FindPath('Mods').Count;
            SetLength(Mods, n);
            for i := 0 to n-1 do
              Mods[i] := JData.FindPath('Mods['+IntToStr(i)+']').AsString;
          except
          end;
        except
        end;
      finally
        JParser.Free;
      end;
    except
      try
        FStream.Free;
        FStream:=TFileStream.Create('config.json',fmOpenWrite);
        JData := GetJSON('{}');
        JObject := TJSONObject(JData);
        GamePath := ExpandFileName('./');
        UserPath := GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA');
        jObject.Add('GamePath', GamePath);
        jObject.Add('UserPath', UserPath);
      except
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась вообще не связана с исключениями. Вместо:

```
FStream:=TFileStream.Create('config.json',fmOpenWrite);
```

надо использовать

```
FStream:=TFileStream.Create('config.json', fmCreate);
```

В половине справок по этому классу такой режим работы с файлами просто не указан, но он есть.

Comment: Не знаю в каких справках вы смотрите, в справке Delphi этот параметр описан хорошо. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Только в справке Дельфи ещё много чего написано, непременимого в моём случае. Так что я смотрел доки по Лазарусу.

Comment: В таком случае, это повод внести изменения в справку Лазаруса :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  FStream: TFileStream;
  FStreamWriter: TStreamWriter;
const
  CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.json';
begin
  if FileExists(CONFIG_FILE_NAME) then
  begin
    FStream := TFileStream.Create(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, fmOpenRead);
    try
      JParser := TJSONParser.Create(FStream);
      try
        // ... читаем конфиг
      finally
        JParser.Free;
      end;
    finally
      FStream.Free; // убрать, если TJSONParser сам удаляет переданный ему Stream
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    FStreamWriter := TStreamWriter.Create(CONFIG_FILE_NAME);
    try
      // ... готовим конфиг
      FStreamWriter.Write(JObject.ToString{или как там это делается}); // записываем в файл
    finally
      FStreamWriter.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

А вот это ваше

```
except
end;
```

уберите и никогда так не делайте. Иначе это плохо кончится когда программа станет большой и толстой, будете очень долго искать почему что-то не работает.

Comment: Lazarus. Класс TStreamWriter - примочка Delphi, и мне не полезна ничем.

Comment: Тогда используйте `FStream := TFileStream.Create(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, fmCreate);`

Comment: Так уже. Посмотрите мой ответ на вопрос.